# Add items to a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

My app is hitting a WebAPI that returns some JSON records.  I get them via jQuery AJAX and assign the JSON to a JavaScript variable.  I can loop through and make changes to existing items without issue.  However, how do I add more "records" to this object? I'm trying to understand the structure of the resulting variable.

Here is what I have as a test.  Is this the best way?

```
var trustAccounts = {"accounts":[
  {"entityId":12345,
  "type":"IOLTA",
  "nameOnAccount":"Sam Smith Trust",
  "accountNumber":"987654",
  "bankCode":"003",
  "bankName":"Bank of Stuff",
  "accountDate":"12/15/2014",
  "status":"A",
  "exempt":"N",
  "accountId":142922,
  "action":"U"}]};

  var newaccount = {};
    newaccount.entityId = 23456;
    newaccount.type = "IOLTA";
    newaccount.nameOnAccount = "John Smith Trust";
    newaccount.accountNumber = "789456";
    newaccount.bankCode = "003";
    newaccount.bankName = "Bank of Stuff";
    newaccount.accountDate = "12/15/2014";
    newaccount.status = "A";
    newaccount.exempt = "N";
    newaccount.accountId = 142923;
    newaccount.action = "U";

  trustAccounts.accounts.push(newaccount);

  console.log(trustAccounts);
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code,  in order we have a common base for discussion? Thanks !

Comment: I assume the JSON is an array of objects? In that case you need to create a new Object, then add it using `records.push(newRecord);`

Comment: *"I'm trying to understand the structure of the resulting variable."*: and you think that without seeing your JSON, ... we can?

Answer (score 1):

So if we name the returned variable `object` we can simply create new elements using `object.newItemName`. Eg below:

```
object.newItemName = 'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add them, as if they already existed. A JSON-parsed object is just a normal JavaScript object.

```
let obj = {};
obj.newProp = 5;
console.log(obj.newProp); // 5

obj['newProp'] = 4;
console.log(obj.newProp); // 4
```

You can set them in two ways, with the dot-notation or with square brackets (`[]`). The dot-notation way, the value after the dot is what it's called. The square bracket can accept a string or variable, so you can use it to set a property to a specific name.

If you need to nest things, you have to create each level. For example, if you wanted to set `obj.something.aValue`, you could do something like this:

```
let obj = {};
obj.something = {};
obj.something.aValue = 5;
```

Or, you can also do it in fewer shots, depending what you're doing:

```
let obj = {
    something: {
        aValue = 5;
    }
};
```